# create-react-app uses modules despite not showing in package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm

From what I understand the `create-react-app` command installs all we need to get started, and more. I am currently trying to get ESLint AirBnB & Prettier to work, and eslint needs quite a few dependencies.

When browsing my `node_modules`, I noticed that `eslint-config-airbnb` AND `eslint-config-airbnb-base` were listed. In `package.json` I have `"eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",` listed **only**.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but my assumption now is that all those packages which have peer dependencies still work fine with each other despite not all being listed in package.json. Is this based on `create-react-app` hiding most of the config from us? Any additional input you can give me about the topic?

The above modules and dependencies are really just representative of the theoretical question as a whole. I am using eslint config as an example.

Cheers

EDIT: I used the eslint example because I actually did have an issue with it not loading correctly, nor linting correctly. I fixed the issue by moving the `.eslintrrc.js` out of the project directory, and into the parent directory. Why this works, I have no idea

Comment: this has nothing to do with `create-react-app`, it's simply how npm3 manages dependencies. `eslint-config-airbnb` depends on `eslint-config-airbnb-base`, so both packages are installed

Comment: @Hamms I don't think you understood. Create-react-app hides the configuration and doesn't list modules used in the package.json. The question is whether I need to install it so that it appears in package.json in addition to already resting in node_modules

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the dependencies when a CRA is ejected (so I'm venturing a guess that yes, you will need to install it, as neither is listed)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^5.0.2",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.0.6",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^6.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.9",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.2"
  },
```

On that note, you may want to move away from the CRA and build your own webpack. :)

Otherwise, there's a good chance you'll run into issues further down the line.

Comment: I have read up a lot about it but shied away from it until this point. Any good resources for best practices in regards to performance ?

Comment: To be honest, the create-react-app is essentially a glorified `webpack-dev-server`. You can build your own (I did) and you can expect the same performance. Thankfully, it has a really good doc that explains its options and their effects: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/